# HTML appended through jQuery doesn't receive margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a normal HTML page that contains some boxes which have a little margin from each other:

[image: With margin]

When an user scrolls down, the page automatically loads more images through AJAX and appends more boxes to the page, but they are glued to each other:

[image: Without margin]

They actually have the same HTML and they shouldn't be looking like that. This is the HTML of a box that comes directly with the page:

```
<div class="images inner">
{% for image in S_IMAGES %}
<span class="image{% if loop.last %} last-box{% endif %}">
    <div class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</div>
    <section class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12 center upload-output">
                <br /><br />

                <div class="img-container">
                    <div class="helper"></div>
                    <a href="{{ S_IMAGES_PATH }}{{ image.image_name }}.{{ image.image_extension }}" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="images">
                        <img src="{{ S_THUMBS_PATH }}{{ image.image_name }}.{{ image.image_extension }}" class="img-thumbnail">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </section>
    <hr />
    <div role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="{{ S_WEB_PATH }}image/{{ image.image_name }}" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon">View</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="{{ S_IMAGES_PATH }}{{ image.image_name }}.{{ image.image_extension }}" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon">Direct</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="{{ S_THUMBS_PATH }}{{ image.image_name }}.{{ image.image_extension }}" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon">Thumb</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
{% else %}

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this is how I append the additional boxes with jQuery:

```
for (var key in response.images) 
{
    var image = response.images[key];

    var imageHTML = '<span class="image' + ((imagesLength == key) ? ' last-box' : '') + '">';
    imageHTML += '<div class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</div>';
    imageHTML += '<section class="row">';
    imageHTML += '<div class="col-lg-12 center upload-output">';
    imageHTML += '<br /><br />';
    imageHTML += '<div class="img-container">';
    imageHTML += '<div class="helper"></div>';
    imageHTML += '<a href="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/i/' + image.image_name + '.' + 
                  image.image_extension + '" class="lightview">';
    imageHTML += '<img src="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + 
                  image.image_extension + '" class="img-thumbnail" />';
    imageHTML += '</a>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '</section>';
    imageHTML += '<hr />';
    imageHTML += '<div role="form">';
    imageHTML += '<div class="form-group">';
    imageHTML += '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">';
    imageHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="' + generate_site_url() + 'image/' + image.image_name + '" readonly>';
    imageHTML += '<span class="input-group-addon">View</span>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">';
    imageHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/i/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '" readonly>';
    imageHTML += '<span class="input-group-addon">Direct</span>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">';
    imageHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" value="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '" readonly>';
    imageHTML += '<span class="input-group-addon">Thumb</span>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '</div>';
    imageHTML += '</span>';

    $('.images').append($(imageHTML));
    $('.image').slideDown('fast');
}
```

LESS for such a box:

```
span.image {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 271px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid @lighten; 
    background-color: lighten(@lighten, 6%);
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;

    @media (max-width: 1200px){
        width: 296px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px){
        width: 336px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        width: 432px;
    }

    .img-container {
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 4px;
        /* background-color: lighten(@light-grey, 10%);
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid @light-grey; */

        .helper {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }

    .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 125px;
        max-height: 125px;  
    }
}
```

What is it that I'm not seeing which is making those boxes stick to each other?

Help would be appreciated.

---

## EDIT

Here's the HTML which was copied from the rendered browser format (Console):

```
<span class="image" style="">
    <div aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</div>
    <section class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12 center upload-output">
                <br><br>

                <div class="img-container">
                    <div class="helper"></div>
                    <a data-lightview-group="images" class="lightview" href="http://localhost/imgzer/store/i/e9K7P8V3z6o4.jpg">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/imgzer/store/t/e9K7P8V3z6o4.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </section>
    <hr>
    <div role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/image/e9K7P8V3z6o4" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">View</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/store/i/e9K7P8V3z6o4.jpg" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Direct</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/store/t/e9K7P8V3z6o4.jpg" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Thumb</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

And this is another box from the console, but which gets added later through AJAX:

```
    <span class="image" style="">
    <div aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</div>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 center upload-output">
            <br><br>
            <div class="img-container">
                <div class="helper"></div>
                <a class="lightview" href="http://localhost/imgzer/store/i/l1I6a4Z1u9L7.jpg">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/imgzer/store/t/l1I6a4Z1u9L7.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <div role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/image/l1I6a4Z1u9L7" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">View</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/store/i/l1I6a4Z1u9L7.jpg" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Direct</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="http://localhost/imgzer/store/t/l1I6a4Z1u9L7.jpg" onclick="this.select();" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Thumb</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

---

## The question

Does anyone have a nice workaround for this? How do I make those boxes look normal? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the console and inspect the elements to see where the styles are coming from

Comment: Post the rendered HTML.

Comment: Hold on. Posting the HTML directly from the console...

Comment: Just a side note, you might find it a lot easier/cleaner to use a javascript template system for such verbose html like that. Mustache, handlebars, underscore, etc.

Comment: Okay. I've added what you've asked for. @helion3 I'm not familiar with what you're saying, could you be more specific?

Comment: Sure. You have a ton of `imageHTML +=` code in which you're building a pretty big html string. It's hard for you to read the html like this, it's hard for IDEs to syntax highlight, and is just a bit ugly. With a template you can build the html with placeholders for your dynamic data. It's much cleaner. There are several amazing templating libraries for js, like http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: what are the extra braces for in the css?  are you using sass?  The reason I ask i because what is written in sass is not what you get in the browser.  so span.image might become div.images span.image { ...

Comment: @RobA He mentions he's using `LESS`

Comment: Ooh, divs in spans. Anyway, the original HTML has `<a data-lightview-group="images"`, where the added HTML doesn't.

Comment: @MrLister I don't really care about the semantics here, I just know that the span isn't an inline elements since I've changed that in CSS. You think that could be causing he issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original HTML code you have spaces between your elements.  When you build the string, your elements are immediately one after another with no space at all.

Add a space:

```
imageHTML += '</span> ';
```

No space:  http://jsfiddle.net/uwE7X/

Space: http://jsfiddle.net/uwE7X/1/

Comment: I feel so blind. Thanks.